# Get value of node with a certain ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have something like:

```
<h1 id="someID">
    <span id="genericID">someValue</span>
</h1>
```

How can I get the value of `genericID` span element, that is, `someValue` using the id ,`someID,` of the h1 element? I can get document.getElementById('oc-title-id').innerHTMLand then do a regex, but is there any other way? Using JQuery or Javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use    `$('#someID').text()`

Or for javascript only `document.getElementById('someID').innerHTML`

Comment: Just remember to have it after the element exists, ideally wrapped inside `$(document).ready()` or as event handler.

Comment: Sure thing.. another thing worth mentioning, `innerHTML` is not the same as jQuery `.text()` method.

Comment: What if I had nested elements and I wished to get the value of the second element using the parents elements ID? IS there an easier way to do this other than to do what you said and then do a regex?

Comment: I believe `$('#someID').eq(1).text()` will do that.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same using JavaScript?

Comment: There are a variety of ways to do it with jQuery, depending on how you want to identify the child you are interested in. Doing it with plain js would not be nearly as concise.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
$('#someID').text();
```

Since a `span` doesn't have a value (though `input` elements do).

You could, potentially, use:

```
$('#someID').html();
```

But that, as the method-name implies, also retrieves the html of any nested elements.

Answer (score 2):

Either `$('#someID').html()` or `$('#someID').text()`, depending on exactly what you want to extract.